# Mathematical induction: $p ∧(q_1 ∨ \cdots∨q_n) = (p∧q_1)∨\cdots∨(p∧q_n)$

Tags: induction

> Prove that for every positive integer $n$, $$p ∧(q_1 ∨ \cdots∨q_n) = (p∧q_1)∨\cdots∨(p∧q_n).$$

This is a mathematical induction question. What would I test for the base case and how? Any help on how to start would be appreciated.

Comment: For the base case, take $n=1$: $p\land q_1=p\land q_1$, simply.

Comment: Base case is $n = 1$, take two positive integers $p$ and $q$ and check the formula (which is absolutely trivial in this case). Then try to go to larger values of $n$ by induction.

Comment: @Gâteau-Gallois: integers ??

Comment: $n$ is an integer, $p$ and $q_i$ are boolean variables or expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at two base cases, $n=1$ and $n=2$. When $n=1$, $p \land q_1 = p \land q_1$ trivially. When $n=2$, use a truth table to prove $p \land (q_1 \lor q_2) = (p \land q_1) \lor (p \land q_2)$ (i.e. check if it is true for all 8 combinations of values for $p$, $q_1$, and $q_2$). Then you can break up $q_1 \lor\cdots\lor q_n$ into $q_1 \lor q'$ with $q'=q_2 \lor\cdots\lor q_n$ for the induction step.